# I want to keep bootstrap modal still show when I click asp.net button

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, button, popup

I want this popup form still show when I click asp.net button ID btnFindSales
Currently, It close when I click this button.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">List of Sales Employee</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row  criteria-box">
            <div class="col-md-6 criteria-item">
                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" style="max-width:280px;" ID="ddlFindOption" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Slp Code</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sales Name</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Position</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 criteria-item">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtFindSales" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnFindSales" runat="server" Text="&#128270;" OnClick="btnFindSales_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom:0;">
            <!-- content goes here -->

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem with asp button id btnFindSales.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: So `btnFindSales_Click` is a server side method right? You'll either need to call some logic that executes after postback that re-opens your popup or instead have it execute that logic via an AJAX call.

Comment: @mason is correct. I think AJAX would be the preferred method, else you would have to do something like `RegisterStartupScript` to re-open the modal when your click event posts back. This is why it sucks to have forms in modal windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for comments above and I found code to fix it.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "squarespaceModal", "$('#squarespaceModal').modal();", true);
```

code above is use for open popup.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "squarespaceModal", "$('#squarespaceModal').modal('hide');", true);
```

and this one for close/hide popup.